# return value from jquery function not working

Tags: jquery, function, return-value

i'm using an ajax function to return a value so i can save it in a variable and use it anywhere but it's not working i get a message : undefined

```
function getData(){
    var ajax = false;
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
    ajax.open("GET","ajax.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            var test = ajax.responseText;
            return test ;
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var n = getData();
    alert(n);
});
```

Comment: AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript + XML. So you would not get the return value immediately as it is async.

Comment: so how to solve this problem ?

Comment: first: if you see your `return` is in `onreadystatechange` function not `getData()`. second: to use asynchronuos request you need another aproach, do you logic inside that `if`

Comment: Continue your code logic inside the success callback `ajax.readyState == 4`.

Comment: any working example to learn from it ?

Comment: If you already use jQuery, just use its ajax function and done handler like following: $.get("ajax.php").done(function(result){ ... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var n = getData();
    alert(n);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your example the function `getData()` does not actually return anything. You are making an AJAX request, and when the AJAX request is successful you say `return data`, but the `getData()` function itself does not return anything. You have a function that returns something (a child function) inside of another function (the parent function). The parent function, which is the function that you are actually calling, doesn't have any return value. This is why you are always seeing "undefined" when you try to alert the result of `getData()`.

Like the commenters above said, AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XML, meaning that your request to get data runs independently of everything else in your script. This is one of the reasons why we have *events*, so you can wait until things have happened before trying to do something with its result.

In your example, you are already listening to the *onreadystatechange* event with this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        var test = ajax.responseText;
        return test ;
    }
}
```

What you need to do is wait until the request is complete before trying to manipulate the data that was returned from the AJAX request. If you store the variable `test` outside of the `getData` function, then it will be available to other functions throughout your script. When the AJAX request was successful, then you can store the data returned in `test` and call another function that does stuff with `test`.

Here's some code to show you what I mean:

```
// Keep "test" globally outside of the scope of getData
// This makes "test" available throughout the rest of the script
var test;


function getData(){

    var ajax = false;
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
    ajax.open("GET","ajax.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

            // This is where we know that the AJAX request has completed
            // so we know we have the data. Store the data in the "test"
            // variable, and call another function here that will do something
            // with "test" - this way "test" won't be undefined!
            test = ajax.responseText;
            doNextStep();
        }
    }

    ajax.send(null);
}

// This new function I've introduced won't get called until
// the Ajax request was successful.
function doNextStep() {
    alert( test );
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    getData();
});
```

Hope this helps!